# CSS - Link in carousel slides jump to wrong position

Tags: css, html

I just made a carousel like so by using some module from my friend.

The problem is after I put `<a>` link to each slide, the link just jumps to the next slides without following the HTML order.

When you switch to slide 2, first, it shows the link of slide 2 (link2) but after about 0.5 secs it jumps to the link of slide 1 (link1). Same as the slide 3 shows the link3 then jump to link2 instantly.

Any idea what just happened?

You can also run the code here on Codepen: https://codepen.io/hanh2122011/pen/rbEmOw

```css
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
  position: static;
  opacity: 100;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
}

.carousel-item img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.carousel-item a {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.carousel-control {
  color: #eaeaea;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  height: 20em;
  width: 10%;
  line-height: 20em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
  vertical-align: middle;

  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
   -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
     -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
      -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
          user-select: none;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
  position: absolute;
}

.carousel-control.next {
  right: 0%;
}


#i1:checked ~ .control-1,
#i2:checked ~ .control-2,
#i3:checked ~ .control-3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">

      <!-- slide 1 -->

      <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="i1" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="" checked="checked">
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a class="slides" target="_blank" href="https://link1.com">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6W3MvYJ/slide1.png">



        </a>
      </div>

      <!-- slide 2 -->

      <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="i2" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a class="slides" target="_blank" href="https://link2.com">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Qvtjrng/slide2.png">

        </a>
      </div>

      <!-- slide 3 -->

      <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="i3" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a class="slides" target="_blank" href="https://link3.com">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/WKVKtmm/slide3.png">
        </a>
      </div>

      <label for="i3" class="carousel-control prev control-1">‹</label>
      <label for="i2" class="carousel-control next control-1">›</label>
      <label for="i1" class="carousel-control prev control-2">‹</label>
      <label for="i3" class="carousel-control next control-2">›</label>
      <label for="i2" class="carousel-control prev control-3">‹</label>
      <label for="i1" class="carousel-control next control-3">›</label>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a stacking order problem and can be solved with [CSS negation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and `z-index`. For non-checked (non-active) carousel items, we'll apply a negative `z-index`, leaving only the active item's link "on top". This will allow the correct link to be accessible at the right time.

Here is what I'm adding to your styles:

```css
.carousel-open:not(:checked)+.carousel-item {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

### Demo

```css
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-open:checked+.carousel-item {
  position: static;
  opacity: 100;
}

.carousel-open:not(:checked)+.carousel-item {
  z-index: -1;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
}

.carousel-item img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.carousel-item a {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.carousel-control {
  color: #eaeaea;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  height: 20em;
  width: 10%;
  line-height: 20em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
  position: absolute;
}

.carousel-control.next {
  right: 0%;
}

#i1:checked~.control-1,
#i2:checked~.control-2,
#i3:checked~.control-3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <!-- slide 1 -->

    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="i1" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="" checked="checked">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <a class="slides" target="_blank" href="https://link1.com">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6W3MvYJ/slide1.png">



      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- slide 2 -->

    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="i2" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <a class="slides" target="_blank" href="https://link2.com">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Qvtjrng/slide2.png">

      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- slide 3 -->

    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="i3" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <a class="slides" target="_blank" href="https://link3.com">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/WKVKtmm/slide3.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <label for="i3" class="carousel-control prev control-1">‹</label>
    <label for="i2" class="carousel-control next control-1">›</label>
    <label for="i1" class="carousel-control prev control-2">‹</label>
    <label for="i3" class="carousel-control next control-2">›</label>
    <label for="i2" class="carousel-control prev control-3">‹</label>
    <label for="i1" class="carousel-control next control-3">›</label>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So the problem is the current slide can not "overlap" the previous slide so the link of the previous link still shown in this slide?

Thank you so much for the solution and a kindly explanation!